# Why do some MTG cards specify "land and/or Gate"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I've been toying with building a Maze's End Commander deck for a while now.

Digging around for cards for such a deck, I came across [Navigation Orb](https://scryfall.com/card/clb/329/navigation-orb) and some other similar cards.

Why does these cards specify "and/or Gate" so often, when there are no Gate cards that aren't also Lands?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you read Navigation Orb, and probably most of those other cards, carefully, they actually specify "basic land and/or Gate", i.e. you can search for any Gate (which are indeed all lands), *or* any basic Island, Mountain, Forest, etc.

Comment: Indeed, I can only find [5 instances](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%2Flands%3F%28+cards%3F%29%3F+%28and%5C%2F%29%3For+gate%2F&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name) of any variation of "land and/or gate", and in all 5, the word "land" is preceded by "basic".

Comment: AHAH, gotcha! So they preclude searching for say, Command Tower or another non-basic, but Gates are fine. Nice.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I wish Gatherer supported some simple regex. It's so much easier to search for many related phrasings at once, and that should really be the default search engine for anything other than market value.

Comment: @Arthur It does: <https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Help.aspx#regex>

Comment: @m90 Why haven't I seen this before? That's awesome, thanks!